# Rails 3 Post/Comments with Formatting (like in stackoverflow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, formatting

I was wondering, it would be great to know how to allow users to format their posts in Ruby on Rails 3. Ideally, i was wondering if there are any gems or solutions to implementing a formatting system similar to stackoverflow, where the user can bold and underline text, and so on (ie provides a little partial above the post input field similar to the one above the input field we use to ask questions).

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still interested in this question, there are a bunch of options for formatting comments and for text editor helpers.

To be brief, I've checked out a whole bunch of options - but I found one that I think is awesome: ckeditor. Check it out at https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor